# Proper PUT implementation and ObjectIDs in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, rest

I would like to use MongoDB's ObjectIDs to identify resources in RESTful calls. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly structure PUT calls.

As I understand it, a proper PUT call path should include the ID of the resource to modify. If the resource with that ID exists, it is modified; if it does not exist, it is created. The latter case is the one I have trouble with: the client making the PUT request does not know the ID that MongoDB will generate, and therefore it cannot use the ID as part of the request.

I imagine this is a fairly common scenario when using auto-generated keys as resource IDs, yet I haven't been able to find an explanation on how to deal with it correctly. I can ditch the idea of using ObjectIDs and use some other value in the document, but that doesn't work well for some kinds of collections. How do others do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [RFC for HTTP/1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6) states that the server can create a new resource if the URI is defined to be used that way.

So if you create new resources by e.g. POSTing to a collections URI, you can return an error response for PUTs with inknown ids.

Comment: Both responses so far are essentially the same, but I'm marking this one as correct due to the link to the RFC. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"if the resource doesn't exist it is created" is IMHO no must. This nice were the resource is identified by name instead of a id like amazon S3. So in your case PUT is only for modifying. For creating POST must be used.